# Foreignfield no value Ormlite

Tags: android, foreign-keys, ormlite

I would like to ask assistance with using Ormlite. I have a class(Node.class) with fields-

```
@DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
public int id;
@DatabaseField
String path;
@DatabaseField
String label;
@DatabaseField
Date lastModified;
@DatabaseField
String resourceType = NODE_TYPE_ENTRY;
@DatabaseField
int status = NODE_STATUS_FRESH;
@DatabaseField
boolean leaf = false;
@DatabaseField
UUID uuid;

@ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
public ForeignCollection<Node> children;
@ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)
public ForeignCollection<Property> properties;
@DatabaseField(foreign = true,index=true)
Node parent;
```

and another class(Classroom.class) with fields

```
@DatabaseField(generatedId=true)
int id;
@DatabaseField
String name;
@DatabaseField
String value;

@DatabaseField(foreign=true,index=true)
Node node;
```

My problem is that, when I add a property , the field node is always 0 and the result should be the id of the created node.

Hoping for your help.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try inserting the node object first, then set it again to your Classroom object and then persist the Classroom object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @k3v1n4ud3's comment is pointing you to the right answer.

You first need to insert the `node` into the `Node` table so the `id` field in the `Node` can be auto-generated and set on the `node` object.  Then you can assign it to the `node` field in the `Classroom` so when you insert `Classroom` into the database, the `node_id` field will be non-0.

To quote the [docs on "foreign objects"](http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-object) in ORMLite:

> When you are creating a field with a foreign object, please note that the foreign object will not automatically be created for you. If your foreign object has a generated-id which is provided by the database then you need to create it before you create any objects that reference it.